# Cordova Timepicker adds 66 minutes on every selection on IPhone/IPad

Tags: javascript, cordova, plugins, ionic-framework

This issue is about the date/time picker plugin for cordova https://github.com/VitaliiBlagodir/cordova-plugin-datepicker/

I am using the datepicker on Android and everything works fine,
but on IPad/IPhone I have the issue that everytime when I select a new time (e.g. 1:00 am ) the returned time is always 66 minutes more than the selected one (2:06 am).
I have tried this also with this datepicker(https://github.com/loiclefloch/cordova-plugin-datepicker)
This happens on IPhone( iOS7.1.2) and IPad (iOS 8.4)

I'm using

```
Cordova CLI: 5.1.1
Ionic Version: 1.0.0-rc.2
Ionic CLI Version: 1.6.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.3.3
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: 3.1.1 
OS: Mac OS X Yosemite
Node Version: v0.12.7
Xcode version: Xcode 6.4 Build version 6E35b
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?
I also created an issue in github for this plugin.